# Visual advanced search in Laravel tables

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, search, tags

I am trying to create visual search form for my Laravel admin panel. I like method and style who use Google. Maybe there is a ready solution who can I simple connect to my database?

I have a big database with many records and I have to create elastic search form.

[image]

[Watch film](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0ikib5j7riqt6h/search.mov?dl=0)

Comment: please add code that you have worked on that shows that you have invested in research.

Comment: add php code here?